# Error "Delimiter not found" when insert data to Redshift by Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I create a table in Redshift that has 5 columns as below:

```
create table store(
  sku varchar(50),
  product_id varchar(50),
  qty decimal(20,5),
  stock_status varchar(50),
  product_key int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  primary key(product_key));
);
```

While product_key is IDENTITY column and generate.
I use Glue to insert data to this table, data just have 4 columns like this:

```
sku,product_id, qty,stock_status
883942191647,601,0.00,0
883963232575,602,0.00,0
```

I want column product_key could be generated.
But it raise error: An error occurred while calling o138.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Error (code 1214) while loading data into Redshift: "Delimiter not found".
Please recommend a solution to fix this. Thanks.

Update: I found this issue due to I use Glue to upsert data into Redshift. When upsert data, the dataframe input mush have the same number of column with table in Redshift. If not will raise this errors. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an space in one of the headers? What code did you use that generated this error? Do you get this error even with the sample set you supplied (not a similar one, that Exact sample set)?

Comment: yes, it is the sample set. I found this issue caused by the Glue upsert data into Redshift as I update above. Thanks for your comment.